# Difference between two dates appear incorrectly

Tags: sqlite, date

I am trying to find the difference between two dates (Currentdate-Duedate)

I used `Julianday('now')-Julianday(T1.DD)`, the results appear fine when the result are positive (when currentDate > DueDate), but results are incorrect when DueDate > Current Date (negative results appear 1 day lower than expected).

Following statement was tried:

```
Select( CAST((Julianday('now')-Julianday(T1.DD)) As Integer)
```

Example format of the column DD in Database `2017-07-21 00:00:00`.

Comment: What is the type of the DD column? Date? Timestamp?

Comment: Why not use datediff?

Comment: DateType of Column is Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case when julianday('now') > julianday(T1.DD) 
then cast (julianday('now') - julianday(T1.DD) as int) 
else cast ((julianday(T1.DD) - julianday('now')  + 1) as int) 
end 
from test;
```

UPDATE 1:

```
select cast(julianday('now') as int) - cast(julianday(T1.DD) as int) 
from test;
```

UPDATE 2:

```
select cast(julianday(date('now') )- julianday(date(T1.DD)) as int ) 
from test;
```

Comment: you are right, quotes are not needed, since it is a column name

Comment: The Query Returns the correct result but for suppose my DD(DueDate) is 23rd July ) and Current Date is 21st July then it returns 2 ,formula will always be currentDate-DueDate,so I want -2 as result

Comment: select cast(julianday('now') as int) - cast(julianday(T1.DD) as int) from test;   Result shows -1 when DueDate is 2017-07-23  00:00:00

Comment: select cast(julianday(date('now') )- julianday(date(T1.DD)) as int ) 
from test;: It Works:) AWSUM:)